# How do i add functionality to an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, hook

There is an application available for jailbroken iPhones called YourTube which adds extra functionality to the stock YouTube application. Info here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=754439

My question is... how is this possible and how could I do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like YourTube is proprietary software from [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/).